# postgresql: элементы массива в функции

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Двумя запросами к таблице бд postgresql получаю нужные данные, например:

```
select 
body::json->'data'->'msg'                     -- ["txt1", "txt2", "txt3"]
from ...
where ...
;

select 
json_array_length(body::json->'data'->'msg')  -- 3
from ...
where ...
;
```

Хочу их получить из функции, делаю так:

```
arr := ARRAY(select body::json->'data'->'msg' from ... where ...); -- {"[\"txt1\", \"txt2\", \"txt3\"]"}
return array_length(arr, 1);                                       -- 1
```

Как исправить код в функции, чтобы получить количество элементов массива `3`  и перебирать их
так: `arr[i]`. Нужно отрабатывать `null` значения, если будет вместо "txt".

Comment: делать из массива ``json_array_elements_text`` и поместить опять в массив, - напрямую никак?